# Insert chapters into letter document

Tags: sectioning, chapters, letters

I am writing an extensive letter document, and I would like to put a summary and a few chapters inside it. Is it possible to do that?
Here my preamble:

```
\documentclass[boldsubject,italicsignature,smartindent]{letteracdp}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{layaureo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

Comment: [`letteracdp`](ftp://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cdpbundl/letteracdp.cls) does not define `\chapter`, so it's not natively supported. What do you want the chapters to look like? The regular ones you find in `book` or `report`?

Comment: Yes, the regular ones you find in book or report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`letteracdp`](ftp://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cdpbundl/letteracdp.cls) doesn't define `\chapter`, you can copy the required definitions from either [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) or [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) almost verbatim. So, add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{chapter}
\newcommand\chaptername{Chapter}
\newcommand\@chapapp{\chaptername}
\let\chaptermark\@gobble% Or define it otherwise
\newcommand\chapter{\clearpage
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

If you want `\section`s (and others) as well, one can extract the appropriate content from the above classes.

---

Here is a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{letteracdp}% ftp://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cdpbundl/letteracdp.cls
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\makeatletter
\newcounter{chapter}
\newcommand\chaptername{Chapter}
\newcommand\@chapapp{\chaptername}
\let\chaptermark\@gobble% Or define it otherwise
\newcommand\chapter{\clearpage
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{A chapter}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *C.D.P. Bundle*, of which the [`letteracdp`](ftp://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cdpbundl/letteracdp.cls) document class is just one of the components (albeit the main one), also provides the [`articoletteracdp`](ftp://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cdpbundl/articoletteracdp.cls) document class, that allows you to use some of the sectioning commands, namely `\section` and `\paragraph`.  Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass
    [twoside,boldsubject,italicsignature,shortindent]
    {articoletteracdp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% The following is just to demonstrate that bookmarks also work correctly:
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}

\address{
    Gustavo \textsc{Mezzetti}\\
    L.S.U. <<A.~di~Savoia Duca d'Aosta>>\\
    Via del Santo, 57\\
    I--35123\quad Padova\quad Italy
}
\signature{Gustavo}
\place{Padova}



\begin{document}

\begin{letter}
    [Chiunque sia interessato]
    {A chiunque sia interessato\\(\emph{To whom it may concern})}
    [Comandi di sezionamento.\\(\emph{Sectioning commands.})]

\opening{Cari tutti (\emph{dear all}),}

il resto di questa lettera \`{e} scritto solo in inglese.  The rest of this 
letter is written only in English.  Directly after the \verb|\opening| command 
you normally place a short preamble that does not logically belong to any 
section, like this.



\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
% \listoftables also works



\section{The first section}
\label{S:First}

This is the first section.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    Put figure contents here.
    \caption{A figure}
    \label{fig:?}
\end{figure}

This is a reference to fig.~\ref{fig:?}.



\section{The second section}
\label{S:Second}

This section also contains paragraphs, the first one of which is 
Paragraph~\ref{P:Foo}.

\paragraph{A nifty paragraph}
\label{P:Foo}
Notice that the period at the end of the paragraph title is inserted
automatically (but see Paragraph~\ref{P:Bar}).

\paragraph{Does this always happen?}
\label{P:Bar}
No, not always: if you already supply a punctuation mark at the end of title,
another one isn't inserted.

This paragraph still belongs to Section~\ref{S:Second}, of course.



\epilogue
The \verb|\epilogue| command introduces some text that does not belong 
logically to the last section; it is best to use it even if you have no such 
text, just before \verb|\closing|.

\closing*{Best regards.}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Sectioning example]

When I wrote the bundle, I deemed sections and paragraphs were enough for letters: I would never ever expect that anybody wanted to include a book-style chapter heading in a letter!  Bear in mind that a document class has a specific document layout associated with it, which you should not upset.  The sectioning commands provided by the `articoletteracdp` document class are crafted to fit nicely with the general design of the `letteracdp` class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a screenshot in order to show some example

Comment: You're right, I haven't.  Please wait until I learn how to do... :-)