# Insert paragraphs and subparagraphs into letter document

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs, letters

A few weeks ago I aksed for
[Insert chapters into letter document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163856/insert-chapters-into-letter-document/163860) but now I need to add paragraphs and subparagraphs into letter document. The previous answer says that I need to copy those commands from book.cls or report.cls, but when I tried to reply the action the user did to import Chapter commands into the document, I saw that it was not a simply copy and paste, but certain lines of code have been accurately selected, and others omitted. So I ask for your help again.

Here my preamble

```
\documentclass[boldsubject,italicsignature,smartindent]{letteracdp}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{layaureo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, similar to the [last answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163856/insert-chapters-into-letter-document/163860), you will need to pull in the lines appropriate to `paragraph` and `subparagraph`.  These use some different things to make the headings, including different ways of spacing and indenting the sections.  I've annotated a few things in the MWE below.  See also [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31795/47522) for more about how the `\@startsection` command works so you can change some of these parameters yourself.

I have not included your previous solution (adding chapters) for clarity of this solution.  The two can co-exist very nicely.

The MWE now becomes:

```
\documentclass[boldsubject,italicsignature,smartindent]{letteracdp}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{layaureo}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{blindtext} % Just for demo

%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
%%% Add paragraphs and subparagraphs
\newcounter {paragraph}
\newcounter {subparagraph}[paragraph]
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
%% The subparagraph indents by \parindent, which is set to 72.12128pt or roughly an inch
%% Redefine it in the letter body (after \opening) if you would like it smaller
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}[John Doe]{
Prof.~John \textsc{Doe}\\
Department of Electrical Engineering\\
Stanford University\\
Stanford, CA~94305 (U.S.A.)
}[
This is the optional subject of the letter.
]
\opening{Dear Prof.~Doe,}

% Change the paragraph indent here if desired
\setlength\parindent{1cm}

\blindtext

\paragraph{This is a paragraph} \blindtext

\subparagraph{This is a subparagraph} \blindtext

\closing{Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

This presents (in part):

[image: letter]

Answer (score 1):

I too refer you to the answer I gave to [a previous similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163856/insert-chapters-into-letter-document/163860): use the `articoletteracdp` documentclass, that comes with `\section`s and `\paragraph`s already defined.